# train_test_split error: "not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 2)"

Tags: python, data-analysis, data-modeling

I am trying to split my dataframe into training and test sets but get the following error on the last line:

"not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 2)"

Below is my code:

```
# import data
df_nyc = pd.read_csv('AB_NYC_2019.csv')

# View data frame
df_nyc.head(10)

# Checking for null values
print(df_nyc.info())

#Checking for outliers
print(df_nyc.describe())

#Categorical variables to be mapped with cat.code. 
df_nyc['neighbourhood_group']= df_nyc['neighbourhood_group'].astype("category").cat.codes
df_nyc['neighbourhood'] = df_nyc['neighbourhood'].astype("category").cat.codes
df_nyc['room_type'] = df_nyc['room_type'].astype("category").cat.codes
df_nyc.info()

plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
sns.distplot(df_nyc['price'], fit=norm)
plt.title("Price Distribution Plot",size=15, weight='bold')

#Since division by zero is a problem, log+1 transformation used.

df_nyc['price_log'] = np.log(df_nyc.price+1)

#Using log transformation, now price feature have normal distribution.

plt.figure(figsize=(12,10))
sns.distplot(df_nyc['price_log'], fit=norm)
plt.title("Log-Price Distribution Plot",size=15, weight='bold')

  
#Prepare data for modeling: First, non-nominal data and old price feature eliminated.

m_nyc = df_nyc.drop(columns=['name','id' ,'host_id','host_name', 
                                   'last_review','price'])
m_nyc.isnull().sum()

#Number of reviews feature has some missing data. 
#For this feature, missing data will be replaced with mean. 
#Since the data is more symmetric, mean replacement is used.

mean = m_nyc['reviews_per_month'].mean()
m_nyc['reviews_per_month'].fillna(mean, inplace=True)
m_nyc.isnull().sum()

# Scaling
scaler = StandardScaler()
m_nyc = scaler.fit_transform(m_nyc)

#divide into training and test sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(m_nyc, train_size = 0.7, test_size=0.3,random_state=100)
```

Anyone know why this error is showing on the last line?

Comment: You're only splitting one array (equivalent of `train_test_split(X)`), but assigning values as if you're splitting two arrays (equivalent of `train_test_split(X,y)`). That's where you run into a problem (also, you don't need to specify both `train_size` and `test_size`, one of them is enough)